# What's the difference between uniqueness case_insensitive:true and case_sensitve:false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a difference between these two validations?

Both seems pass the tests,

```
  validates :username,
            presence: true,
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  validates :value,
            presence: true,
            uniqueness: { case_insensitive: true }
```

Comment: Can I see the tests for the context?

Comment: I just realised you were using a non-valid case_insensitive there, so @mdesantis answer is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `case_insensitive: true` is not a valid option and will be ignored; you should use `case_sensitive: false`. Check [`validates_uniqueness_of` docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) for the available options.

If your tests pass they are bugged.